# How to install VidyoDesktop on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: dependencies, 16.04

I recently moved to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I noticed that `VidyoDesktop` was no longer available on my system. I tried to install it from the deb package using `dpkg` but I received the following error:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i VidyoDesktopInstaller-ubuntu64-TAG_VD_3_6_3_017.deb 
[...]
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di vidyodesktop:
 vidyodesktop dipende da libqt4-gui (>= 4.8.1); comunque:
  libqt4-gui not installed.
```

I've noticed that `libqt4-gui` is not present in Ubuntu 16.04 repository. Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thank you

Edit:
My question is different from "How to install a deb file with dpkg". In fact I was asking how to install a specific package with a missing dependance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the following link by Vidyo suggests,

https://support.vidyocloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/226103528-VidyoDesktop-3-6-3-for-Linux-and-Ubuntu-15-04-and-higher

one just needs to eliminate dependency on `libqt4-gui` (again, this case is already mentioned in previous answers but this is yet another approach.)

If I may, let me copy the solution from the above link and paste it here.
I just made changes in the 3rd and 4th steps where I mention using *vim* editor instead of *nano*.

**1) Download the VidyoDesktop .deb file to your home directory**

**2) Run the following commands from the terminal (replacing "vidyodesktop.deb" with the exact filename according to your system type)**

```
$ cd ~
$ dpkg-deb -x vidyodesktop.deb vidyobuild
$ dpkg-deb --control vidyodesktop.deb vidyobuild/DEBIAN
```

**3) Edit the package control file**

```
$ vim vidyobuild/DEBIAN/control
```

Replace the entire Depends: line by copying and pasting the following:

```
Depends: libxss1,libaudio2,libasound2,libqt4-network
```

***This removes the libqt4-gui transitional package dependency which is no longer required for recent Ubuntu versions***

4) Save the customized .deb file

*esc*

```
:wq
```

*enter*

```
$ dpkg-deb -b vidyobuild vidyodesktop-custom.deb
```

5) Install the new VidyoDesktop .deb file by running

```
$ sudo dpkg -i vidyodesktop-custom.deb
```

**[EDIT: Vidyo desktop works only in wifi mode. If the LAN cable is connected, then Vidyo shuts down. I haven't found a solution to this problem yet. But rest is working!]**

Comment: https://information-technology.web.cern.ch/comment/69#comment-69

Comment: In addition to this, I found that in order to avoid seg faults: 
/usr/bin/VidyoDesktop: line 6:  3085 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /opt/vidyo/VidyoDesktop/$EXEC $option $audioflag $@
one needs to enable the "always use VidyoProxy" in the options.

Comment: @AndreaBorga How do you go about enabling that option if VidyoDesktop won't launch due to the segfaults?

Comment: @gene_wood mine was seg faulting when joining a meeting.

Answer (score 13):

The solution provided by Andrea works, but I'd like to report the exact command:

```
 sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=libqt4-gui VidyoDesktopInstaller-ubuntu64-TAG_VD_3_6_3_017.deb
```

Comment: This works but Ubuntu's software center will complain and annoy you with warnings about broken packages due to missing dependencies (the one you chose to ignore).

Comment: with above solution vidyo got installed but it is not starting up

Answer (score 3):

My workaround has been to build a dummy libqt4-gui transitional package, using a control file based on the qt4-x11 source package and the equivs tools:

```
sudo apt install equivs
wget http://fwyzard.web.cern.ch/fwyzard/ubuntu/libqt4-gui/control
equivs-build control
sudo dpkg -i libqt4-gui_4.8.7_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: This worked for me. But I had to install some other packages first: apt install libqt4-designer libqt4-svg

Comment: Please change the accepted answer to @fwyzard's reply. The currently accepted answer is only relevant to CERN users.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved by forcing install without checking dependencies (google for the exact dpkg command). You will still have a formally broken package on your system, but apparently VidyoDesktop works smoothly also without libqt4-gui...

Does anybody know why the package was dropped? I suspect this will create problems to several 3rd party packages...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here for a modified VidyoDesktop installer without the dependency on libqt4-gui:

https://information-technology.web.cern.ch/comment/28#comment-28

> NOTE: This link is no longer publicly visible, and may not provide useful information anymore.

Please note that it is a CERN protected page, so I prefer not to post the full link here, since the VidyoDesktop package is not free software

Comment: It works, but it is a CERN protected page, so it is not reachble by external users. If a mod tell me I can put a link to the gdrive where the modified deb package is, then I will edit this comment with this additional information. Thanks

Comment: [CERN Vidyo Downloads](http://information-technology.web.cern.ch/services/fe/downloads/Vidyo)

Comment: the link points to: https://support.vidyocloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/226103528-VidyoDesktop-3-6-3-for-Linux-and-Ubuntu-15-04-and-higher

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to manually download libqt4-gui and its following dependent packages from [URL](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libqt4-gui).

1. libqt4-designer
2. libqt4-opengl
3. libqt4-svg
4. libqtgui4

Comment: The command you suggested results in disinstalling vidyodesktop

Comment: @K.K Patel, this will not work, as the package "libqt4-gui" is not available in the 16.04 repositories.

Comment: Yep, same problem here, but installing open365 deb package. Looks like libqt4 has been removed from ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @Matteo S.  Please check it now. I edited answer.

Comment: the solution proposed by @MatteoS. is more effective and avoids fiddling around with officially discontinued libraries.